# overloaded operator << on ofstream concatenation problems

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, concatenation, ofstream

I have the following code:

```
struct simple
{
    simple (int a1, int a2) : member1(a1), member2(a2) {}
    int member1;
    int member2;
};

std::ofstream &operator << (std::ofstream &f, const simple &obj)
{
    f<<obj.member1<<", "<<obj.member2;
    return f;
} 
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    std::ofstream f("streamout.txt");

    simple s(7,5);
    f << s;               //#1 This works
    f << "label: " << s;  //#2 This fails

    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to understand why #1 works, while there are problems when trying to use the overloaded operator concatenating it as in #2 which fails with the following error (gcc 4.5.3 on MacOSX):

> error: cannot bind
>   'std::basic_ostream' lvalue to
>   'std::basic_ostream&&'
>   /GCC-FACTORY/4.5/INSTALL/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin10.5.0/4.5.3/../../../../include/c++/4.5.3/ostream:579:5:
>   error:   initializing argument 1 of
>   'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&
>   std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT,
>   _Traits>&&, const _Tp&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits =
>   std::char_traits, _Tp = simple]'

Everything is instead fine if I define my operator as

```
std::ostream &operator << (std::ostream &f, const simple &obj)
{ ... }
```

Sounds like something related to overload resolution, where having a something inserted in the ofstream for which there's already a provided overload (the const char * "label" in this case) breaks up following overload resolution, but I can't really understand what exactly is going on here.
I'd like to get a clear picture of what the compiler's trying to do..

Comment: I don't know specifically why the compiler complains, but overloading for `ostream` (i.e. the common base class) is the correct thing to do, as it allows it to be used for all sorts of output streams.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

On the line :

```
f << "label: " << s;
```

Because the first call to `operator<<` returns a `std::ostream &`, the second fails to compile : the left operand to the operator is not of type `std::ofstream` anymore and your overload is not found.

You should really use the second signature, as I see no reason for restricting your type to be outputted to `std::ofstream`.

Comment: You can farther generalize the function to work with any character traits if you use the signature `template<class Ch,class Tr> std::basic_ostream<Ch,Tr>& operator<<(std::basic_ostream<Ch,Tr>& s, const simple& obj);`