# unable to overload ofstream operator due to - cannot bind to value of unrelated type (stroustrup c++ chapter 10)

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, ofstream, ostream, stack-memory

Background:

I am working my way though Stroustrup's c++ book. I am on chapter 10 completing the drills and come across a problem. Now, as far as I can tell I am not strictly following the book, based on how I have seen others answer the questions. I guess Im just after a little more understanding on how to implement the code.

My general aim is to have a write function rather than have it in main().

The aim of the following function is to return an ofstream.

```
ofstream& c_data_file()
{
    string oname = "mydata.txt";
    ofstream ost {oname};
    if (!ost) {
        string error = "cannot open " + oname;
        throw runtime_error(error);
    }
    return ost;
}
```

This code does come with a warning from the compiler and I am including it, as it may be related to the problem. The warning is:

> Reference to stack memory associated with local variable 'ost'
>   returned

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Point& p)
{
    return os << "(" << p.x <<"," <<p.y <<")";
}

ofstream& operator<<(ofstream& ost, const Point& p)
{
    return ost << "(" << p.x <<"," <<p.y <<")";
}
```

the ostream works fine (i use this stream else where). The ofstream does not work, returning the error:

> Non-const lvalue reference to type 'ofstream' (aka
>   'basic_ofstream') cannot bind to a value of unrelated type
>   'basic_ostream >'

The following is the rest of the relevant code:

```
int main() {

    vector<Point> original_points;
 ofstream& ost = c_data_file();
    for (int i = 0; i<original_points.size(); i++) {
        ost << original_points[i] << "\n";
    }
    ost.close();
}
```

I have been looking online all day, the following question seems the closet:

[overloaded operator << on ofstream concatenation problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640994/overloaded-operator-on-ofstream-concatenation-problems)

However, i find it hard to understand the answer and from what i do understand it does not solve my issue.

Thank you for reading and for any help you can give.

I am including the following edit here as well as my response to iksemyonov with the hope to clearly express the problem for everyone.
Edit1: The warning was resolved following advice from TBBle.  The main issue still stands, as the link indicates and iksemyonov suggests I should use ostream instead of ofstream. This is problematic. Ostream is (following the book) used to send data to cout which is what i am doing (code not present). I also want to send the same data to a file (ideally as the book suggests via ofstream).

Edit 2: following the link and iksemyonov's suggestions worked. A number of the comments below helped me execute the suggestions. So thank you to everyone who commented.

Comment: The first warning is because your'e indeed returning a reference to temporary `ost`, which is created on the stack. That can result in a crash since once `ost` goes out of scope after the function returns, it's *not guaranteed* to exist, as it *may* sooner or later be deleted. Thus the warning.

Comment: You're returning a reference to a local variable.  That is **undefined behavior**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the link provided by OP,

[overloaded operator << on ofstream concatenation problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640994/overloaded-operator-on-ofstream-concatenation-problems)

other than fixing the *returning reference to temporary* error, the fix is to change

```
ofstream& operator<<(ofstream& ost, const Point& p)
{
    return ost << "(" << p.x <<"," <<p.y <<")";
}
```

to

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& ost, const Point& p)
{
    return ost << "(" << p.x <<"," <<p.y <<")";
}
```

which compiles just fine. As the answer in the link describes, the reason for the error to occur is that `ost << "("` returns an object of type `ostream`, and the further calls to `operator<<` thus fail because of the incompatibility reported by the compiler.

On a side note, it is not a good style to not return an exit code from main, as in `return 0`.

Comment: Ok, my problem with this is that I am already using ostream to send data to cout. Can i also use it at the same time to send data to a file (or ost)? I just tried removing ofstream and keeping only the ostream and that created a linker error and another error.

Comment: What's the "another error"? This answer is correct. An `ofstream` is an `ostream`, so providing just one `ofstream& operator<<(ofstream&, const Point&)` should fulfil both use-cases.

Comment: Ok its working now. Simply by removing ofstream, but properly this time. I forgot the linker in the header.h file, I feel like an idiot.

Comment: Not returning an exit code is not incorrect; the compiler is required to behave as if you ended `main` with `return 0;`.

Comment: fixed to be "bad style" which was what I actually meant.

Answer (score 1):

You have created an local `ofstream` in your function, so you can't return a reference to it, as it's gone after your function ends.

So you have to return an `ofstream` object instead.

[You can't copy streams](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6010930/166389), so it'll have to be a move. Luckily, that'll be automatic in this case. (Assuming C++11. If not, you need to restructure your code).

And if you're on gcc before gcc 5, [you can't move streams due to a bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28775806/166389).

So the simplest change to your function is:

```
ofstream c_data_file()
{
    string oname = "mydata.txt";
    ofstream ost {oname};
    if (!ost) {
        string error = "cannot open " + oname;
        throw runtime_error(error);
    }
    return ost;
}
```

and the caller becomes

```
ofstream ost = c_data_file();
```

Comment: TBBle, the error seems to be indeed the one described by OP in his link. Namely, that `os << "("` returns an `ostream`, not an `ofstream`. Could you explain the details why that happens? That's the line where the error occurs, checked with a compiler.

Comment: Actually, I'd overlooked that this was the error, I was looking at the warning. Your answer above addresses the actual issue.

Comment: Thank you TBBle, this fixed the warning. But has not resolved the main issue.

Answer (score 0):

`ofstream& c_data_file()` is returning a reference `(&)` to an `ofstream ost;` which no longer exists (`ofstream ost;` is a local object and is gonna be destroyed once it goes out of scope)

so what you could do instead is modify your function to `ofstream c_data_file()` and this way you will no longer return a temporary object.